# How to trigger a click event ondocument ready but not on a component, just on the "screen"

Tags: javascript

I need to trigger a click event on document ready but I just want the click to be "on the screen" not on any component at all, any way to do this? do I need to pass the form id as the argument to achieve this or what is the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
$(function() {
  // setting up a test to show something happens
  $(document).on("click",function() { alert("clicked") } );
  
  // triggering the click itself
  $(document).trigger("click");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you this code works for my case $(document).trigger("click");

Answer (score 0):

If you need to click anywhere in the body of the page, you can use the jquery .on() with reference to $(document).

```
$(document).on('click', function(){
    // your code to execute on click event
});
```

In case you need a reference to the element you clicked, you can use `$(this)`
Cheers